# SwiftUI - Setting function ID to post.id

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

In my function, I am trying to set (id:) to post.id. Post and ID are in PostModel, which I've referenced as `var post : PostModel`. However, with my current code, I am receiving these errors:

*Variable 'self.post' used before being initialized*

*`self' used in method call 'getComments' before all stored properties are initialized*

*Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties*

My code for this part of my app is here:

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

class CommentsViewModel : ObservableObject{
    
    @Published var comments : [CommentsModel] = []
    @Published var noComments = false
    @Published var newComment = false
    @Published var commentTxt = ""
    
    var post : PostModel
    
    let ref = Firestore.firestore()
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    
    init() {
        getComments(id: post.id) //this has to resort to post.id
    }
    
    func getComments(id: String) {
//code for function
}
```

Inside my getComments function, I am trying to call 'id' like this:
`ref.collection("Posts").document(id).collection("Comments").addSnapshotListener`

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: That error is telling you that you can't access any property or method from `self` without instantiating correctly the object. In your case, since you class has a `post` property that is NOT an optional, you need to define the correct value on initialization, before calling `getComments(id:)`.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

```
var post: PostModel    // <--- not initialised
init(post: PostModel) {
    self.post = post   // <--- now initialised
    getComments(id: post.id) //this has to resort to post.id
}
```

or

```
var post = PostModel(...) // <--- initialised
init() {
    getComments(id: post.id) //this has to resort to post.id
}
```

Comment: I did this, and im getting other errors. Particularly here:

`@StateObject var commentsData = CommentsViewModel()` - Missing argument for parameter 'post' in call

So I add post: PostModel in the () and I get Cannot convert value of type 'PostModel.Type' to expected argument type 'PostModel'

Comment: I've also tried "post: post" in the parameters, and it still throws an error. Unsure where to go from here.

Comment: show us the code you are using, because your comments do not make sense. What is commentsData, and what is "post: post" in the parameters? You can edit your question to show us what you have tried.

Comment: Ill edit my question in a little bit when I have access to my computer. I've worked out what my issue is - post.id is not being passed to the CommentsViewModel. I need to figure out how to pass post.id between my PostRow.swift (view) to my CommentsViewModel (model).